# Wordpress htaccess redirect 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I created htaccess file in wordpress. but redirect rule for css throws 404 not found error. My css file exists in the below location
localhost/mindspark_career/wp-content/plugins/wp-job-manager-alerts/assets/css/frontend.css?ver=4.4.4

and My htaccess is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mindspark_career/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule . /mindspark_career/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^modules/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1?mkxhm_mst=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^modules/172d3920/(.*) /modules/wp-job-manager-alerts/$1?mkxhm_mst=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and My css url is called like below
http://localhost/mindspark_career/modules/172d3920/assets/css/frontend.css?ver=4.4.4

whether my redirect rule is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You want `RewriteRule ^modules/172d3920/(.*)` to match but `RewriteRule ^modules/(.*)` matches first (and the `L`ast flag stops the rewrite anyway).

Reorder your rules, from the most specific to the least specific.

```
RewriteRule ^modules/172d3920/(.*) /modules/wp-job-manager-alerts/$1?mkxhm_mst=1234 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^modules/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1?mkxhm_mst=1234 [QSA,L]
```

Don't forget to enable and check the debug logs for the rewrite module say ([RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) for apache 2.2,
[LogLevel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging) for apache 2.4) if you have troubles with rules that don't apply.

Comment: rules already in the the order you specified only, me only post it in wrong order. but its now loading